# Curl SSL error certificate has expired

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, openssl

I'm doing with python for getting result from API URL. But it happened like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grafana-utils.py", line 95, in <module>
    grafana_backup_all()
  File "/home/trobz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 700, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trobz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 680, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/trobz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 873, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/trobz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 508, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "grafana-utils.py", line 56, in grafana_backup_all
    data = json.loads(api_grafana_get_data(host, key))
  File "grafana-utils.py", line 15, in api_grafana_get_data
    data = requests.get( host + '/api/search', headers=key).text
  File "/home/trobz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trobz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trobz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/trobz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trobz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 511, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='grafana.trobz.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/search (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Curl also the same issue:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I have a look https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html but still don't understand how to solve this issue.

```
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3208 bytes and written 295 bytes
Verification error: certificate has expired
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: D84D38798779A0009ED548D3C05188D46793E9BCEF4F79DA65C47CF27110282F
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 5F60F42E744D123FB51B271E347C9B6690F4E13D4A0D2634D9468B427D5A6C2A6D6DCB855BE2561EF34477A40190890B
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1541057942
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
closed
```

I don't understand this issue only happen with this machine, on my localmachine it work will to connect to the host.

Some people tell me **curl -k host** but I don't like that because insecure.

One more thing, I'm sure the server is OK. so the problem look like from the machine.

Server here:

> ```
> Resolves to   grafana.trobz.com
> Expiration date   Dec 31, 2018
> Vendor signed Yes
> Hostname  Matches
> Key length    2048
> Server type   nginx
> Common name   *.trobz.com
> SAN   *.trobz.com, trobz.com
> Organization  Let's Encrypt
> Common name   Let's Encrypt Authority X3 Let's Encrypt Authority X3
> Serial number 03:1b:2d:bb:65:5d:b4:b2:70:c3:18:45:0a:ea:db:05:62:48
> Signature algorithm   sha256WithRSAEncryption
> Fingerprint (SHA-1)   A35C6987779070AB273471A0E2FA55AB87621822
> Fingerprint (MD5) A4BBF42BED757F638CB273095102E807
> ```

Anyone could help please?

Comment: Can you check if the server is configured right? You might try openssl tool. `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect yourserver:443` Maybe some intermediate certs are missing? It might be an issue with certificate chain. Maybe the issuer's root certificates need to exist in your system.

Comment: Your client machine has a wrong date in the system clock.

Answer (score 4):

> SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

TLS certificates contain two dates and will be **not valid before the start date** and **not valid after the expire date** and verification will fail if the time/date on the client is outside of that time range.

That can have two reasons, the certificate is actually expired, or the clock on your client is off and by a big margin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue while making a CURL call, You can skip it will below curl param (Example for PHP curl call) :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

or

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
```

This is a suggestion to keep the production CURL calls running until you find the root cause of the error "Curl : SSL error certificate has expired"